Install unstable fingerprint sensor EgisTec-EH575 Fedora
I recently installed Fedora on my Acer Swift 3 (SF314-511) and everything is working fine, except the fingerprint sensor. It seems there is no stable driver for it, but I managed to find an experimental driver that seems to work fine, but has high false negatives. This is the GitHub link: https://github.com/Animeshz/EgisTec-EH575. I tried searching online how to install it, but I can´t find an awnser. Does anybody know how to install a driver from the source code? And does installing this unstable driver impact the stability of linux? Thank you in advance!

From the site you reference: "This repository doesn't contain the driver, this is an archive of efforts made to enable this fingerprint sensor integrate with linux desktops."Also, https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:1c7a-0575 states: "We have not found a driver for the device in any Linux kernel... [or] in known additional packages." AFAIK, you have two alternatives: get an external (USB) fingerprint reader that is Fedora-compatible, or use another ID method, e.g.., https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy (untested by me).
